# QML connection Mac difference

Tags: qt, qml

Using the latest version of Qt and Android Studio.
I have had the following code working on Windows environment when working on an Android application.

c++ signal code:

```
signals:
  void serviceSuccess(QVariant method, QVariant data);
```

and somewhere in my code, I emit the signal

```
emit this->serviceSuccess(this->pageSection, jsonString);
```

where `this->pageSection` is a string to hold the calling page and `jsonString` is a string of `QJsonObject` object

In my QML:

```
Connections{
    target: proxySchemaNSession

    onServiceSuccess: {

        if(method === 'progress@validate_session'){
            proxySchemaNSession.retrieveUserPermissions('progress@retrieve_user_permissions');
        }
```

but when developing the Android application on a Mac the variable data is coming back as undefined and data has the value of what method should be.  Not sure where the variable json is coming from since its not defined:

[image]

Any ideas why its different on a Mac?

**Update 1**

I hardcoded my emit method values:

```
emit this->serviceSuccess("should_be_method", "should_be_data");
```

and in the QML the method is still coming back as undefined.  For some reason, the QML Connections thinks onServiceSuccess has three arguments:

[image]

**Update 2**

It seems like that when I run the app and using console.log() the method and data are correct.  But it's incorrect when I step through it.  So i'm wondering why is it different when running and stepping through when both are in debug mode?

Comment: Did yo check with debugger that `this->serviceSuccess` emits real data when `onServiceSuccess:` receives undefined one?

Comment: Yes and for a test I added the following test where I hardcoded the emit values.  I updated my comment above

Comment: OK so if I just run the app and put a console.log() the method and data are correct.  But if I step through the code its incorrect

Comment: Probably some logic issue. You have to post all relevant code so we can test it .